# how to pass two variables to view in controller (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two different queries which are saved in two variables.I want to pass the variables to view page from controller.

```
public function getApprovalList(){
 // $users = select query..
 // $request = select query.. 
   return view('travelerHome',['users'=>$users,'request'=>$request]);
}
```

**solution:**

**controller**

```
return view('travelerHome',['users'=>$users,'requestList'=>$request]);
```

**view**

```
@foreach ($requestList as $req)
  {{$req->traveler_name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return view('travelerHome')->with(array('users'=>$users,'request'=>$request));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `return view('travelerHome', compact('users', 'request'));` too

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
return view('travelerHome')->with('users'=>$users)->with('request'=>$request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code with you have written that is correct, you need to remove the comment only, I am also using the same method for pass the variable to View. Here is the example.

```
return view('admin.product.product.edit', ['product' => $product,
            'attribute_set' => $productAttributes,
            'category' => $cates,
            'images' => $images,
            'status' => $status,
            'countries' => $countries,
            'crane_manufacture' => $crane_manufacture,
            'product_category' => $productCategory]);
    }
```

And it's also working

So, in your code you need to

```
public function getApprovalList(){
   $users = 'select query..';
   $request = 'select query..'; 
   return view('travelerHome',['users'=>$users,'request'=>$request]);
}
```